# Jolt Transform to get particular value if a condition is met

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Input json :

```
{
  "customerPriceBreakUp": [
    {
      "value": 45,
      "componentName": "BASIC_FARE",
      "collectedBy": "VENDOR"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "componentName": "SERVICE_CHARGE",
      "collectedBy": "VENDOR"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "componentName": "SERVICE_TAX",
      "collectedBy": "VENDOR"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "componentName": "VENDOR_INSURANCE_CHARGE",
      "collectedBy": "VENDOR"
    },
    {
      "value": 0,
      "componentName": "TRANSACTION_CHARGE",
      "collectedBy": "XYZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output :

```
{
  "Base_Fare": 45,
  "Service_Charge": 0,
  "Service_Tax": 0,
  "Vendor_Insurance_Charge": 0,
  "Tranaction _Charge": 0
}
```

The "CustomerPriceBreakup" is a list of JSONs, and we need the "value" field.
if "componentName" = "BASIC_FARE" then take the value field and name it "base_fare" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two consecutive transformations such as

```json
[
  // prepare future key names to be lowercase
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "=toLower(@(1,&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // match key and value pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "@(1,componentName)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]